# What's the correct code for this pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I'm not quite getting pseudocode FOR loop thing.

What would be the correct code (in any language) for this pseudocode?

```
function myFunction(arr[])
    for i = 0 to length(arr) 
        if (arr[i] > i) then
            j = i
            while (j < length(arr)) and (arr[j] >= j)
                j = j + 1
            temp = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[j]
            arr[j] = temp
            i = 0
```

Comment: why would you ask that?

Comment: The code in any language with C style syntax will look extremely similar. Why not just ask what the pseudocode does?

Comment: Because to me there's two options here:

it might be:
    for (int i = 0; i < length(arr); i++)
OR it can be:
    while(i < length(arr))
        if (arr[i] > i)
            i = 0;
        else
            i++;

Comment: So, which one is that? :)

Comment: @orsi The pseudocode suggests a for loop, but as you say, a for loop or a while loop can be used equivalently here.

Comment: Not eventually, because in case of for-loop the int i = 0 - doesn't make send, for loop increments it anyway
. With while loop - it's different int really becomes zero in the beginning of next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, in C# (or Java, if you decapitalize "Length"):

```
void myFunction(int[] arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > i) 
        {
            int j = i;
            while(j < arr.Length && arr[j] >= j)
                j = j + 1;
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Using while instead of for:

```
void myFunction(int[] arr)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < arr.Length)
    {
        if(arr[i] > i) 
        {
            int j = i;
            while(j < arr.Length && arr[j] >= j)
                j = j + 1;
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Note the indentation structure of the pseudocode:

```
function myFunction(arr[])
    for i = 0 to length(arr) 
        if (arr[i] > i) then
            ...
```

This means that everything underneath the for declaration is inside the loop, and everything underneath the if, including setting i to 0, will be inside the conditional block. Given this fact, it must be the case that i will start again at 1 if the if statement is entered. What would happen if the code were as below?

```
void myFunction(int[] arr)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < arr.Length)
    {
        if(arr[i] > i) 
        {
            int j = i;
            while(j < arr.Length && arr[j] >= j)
                j = j + 1;
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In the case `arr[i] <= i`, the loop never terminates.

You should always assume the last operation of an iterative loop is the shifting of the index, unless explicitly stated otherwise. This is how a for loop must behave, and how a while implementation ought to (by convention).

The code itself looks to be an attempt at a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) implementation, but is sorting based on comparison against the index, rather than the other elements. I am not sure what it is meant to achieve.

Comment: So in this variant, if arr[i] > i - is true next iteration will start from i = 1, NOT 0? Doesn't pseudocode tell us that it should start from 0 in that case?

Comment: @orsi You are correct about the behavior, but not about what the pseudocode implies. Unless explicitly stated otherwise, you should assume that a loop index incrementation (whether done with for or while/i++) will be the last operation of the loop body. This is how a for loop must behave (as you've stated) and an implementation with while should follow the same conventions. If the code was meant to set i to 0, then why not assign i=-1 before the increment? Also, there's no need to start back at 0 for the sorting.

Comment: Well, that's not sorting algorithm, more like a brain teaser.
That's what I'm trying to understand - does this code explicitly states that i should become 0 at the end of iteration, or it assumes that it will be incremented anyways at the beginning of a new one....

Comment: whouldn't while be more like:

    `while(i<arr.length)
    {if (arr[i] > i) i=0 else i++}`  ?

@EsotericScreenName

Comment: @orsi No. There's no mention of an else in the pseudocode; you're reading too far in to it. If it's not mentioned, it's not there. Also, that code would potentially give an infinite loop as well. For example, if all array elements were > 0. This code has many problems, don't assume that you're misunderstanding the pseudocode because it doesn't function correctly or doesn't make sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30005/discussion-between-esoteric-screen-name-and-orsi)